# Edit Visual Studio .sln file

Tags: visual-studio, azure-data-factory

Exporting a Data Factory project to Visual Studio forces a few things on developers that adds about an hour or so to one's development time per project.

The project IS going to be forced to the Users Documents Visual Studio Projects folder, there WILL be an extra path element the same name as the project and the .sln file WILL be where Microsoft wants it.

This wasn't avoidable and editing the .sln file in Visual Studio of course opens the solution ... always.

Here is how I had to handle Visual Studio 2015 both forcing a new directory for the solution and then making its own folder with the same name for the project.

It will be noted there is no way in Visual Studio to simply open the .sln file and edit it with the handy dandy context sensitive highlighting.  It always opens the solution.

So, I copied the .sln file and renamed the extension to .xml.  Then opened it in Visual Studio and edited it there.

This way I was able to remove everything from the default c:\ partition over to where I like to store info:
1. By client
2. By type of project
3. By folder named for the project
4. .sln and project folder in the same directory level

There may be a better way but at the time I didn't want to Google, I wanted to get my project set up and going.

I'm setting up configuration files for an Azure Data Factory and had downloaded the project from Azure.  By default, it sets up the project on the c:\ partition -- doesn't allow any deviation from this.

So ... copy everything from your VS(Version) Projects:

[image]

Copy it to the new directory:

[image]

Note, I've already removed the extra folder with the same project name.  So the path was D:\Clients\ISSI\Azure Projects\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory.  The extra \MergedDataFactory in the path is removed and the contents pushed up to next higher directory level.

Now, do this. Copy the .sln, rename the extension to .xml.  For me, I then make a copy of the xml and edit that one.

This will open in visual studio and allow editing.

[image]

What is handy is elements of the .sln are identified by GUIDs.  So the only items that need to change are:

1. The path -- put in your desired path
2. Remove the extra project name in the path
3. Put the content where it needs to be

Change this:

```
C:\Users\Michael Durthaler\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory.dfproj
```

To this:

```
D:\Clients\ISSI\Azure Projects\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory.dfproj

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{3466B219-07DB-46AE-8697-CFD2A1650EC8}") = "MergedDataFactory", "C:\Users\Michael Durthaler\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory\MergedDataFactory.dfproj", "{6F37DAB2-09D5-45FB-BBBE-EC6B98E429AC}"
EndProject
Global
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
Release|x86 = Release|x86
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
{6F37DAB2-09D5-45FB-BBBE-EC6B98E429AC}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
{6F37DAB2-09D5-45FB-BBBE-EC6B98E429AC}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
{6F37DAB2-09D5-45FB-BBBE-EC6B98E429AC}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
{6F37DAB2-09D5-45FB-BBBE-EC6B98E429AC}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Next, I rename the copied XML file to .sln.  This way I've got the original .sln, the copied to .xml version and the new .sln file:

[image]

Close out of Visual Studio, double click the new .sln file and see that everything opens as it should:

[image]

Then just delete old files.

It would be nice if Microsoft would not default to the c:\ partition -- this will eventually bloat the c:\ partition because it is a fixed size.  And if they'd see it more practical for a developer to organize as they see fit, that would be great also.

Comment: As this is a Q&A site, you should pose a question and then answer it in an answer instead of putting the answer in the question. I think there is a tickbox to indicate that you are answering your own question specifically for this case.

Comment: That's what I used.  It gave me the Answer area where I put in the answer below.  First time I've used it, probably did the proverbial fat finger ... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around for ADF exports being forced to a certain directory, not allowing the developer the freedom of choice of organizing their projects themselves.